# How to free up memory allocated by "new", but without referencing corresponding pointer explicitly

Tags: c++, pointers

My application has 2 states, say foo and bar. There are some objects associated with each state, but since they are big with respect to memory, I'd like to create them upon entry to the state (using new) and then release the memory allocated when it's time to change states. I have a function corresponding to each state, that returns a void*. This will represent the address of the objects(s) that are relevant while in each state.

So the general idea is

```
void* vPtr;
if (state == foo) { vPtr = foo(); }
else if (state == bar) { vPtr = bar(); }

//then, using the knowledge that all the object(s)
//are located at vPtr, do things with those objects
```

Here's what foo looks like in a nutshell

```
void* foo()
{
    //if first time executing foo, create some new object(s) and return a pointer 
    //to them
    if (firstEntry)
    {
        firstEntry = false; 
        Thing *thingPtr = new Thing; //create new Thing
        return (void*)thingPtr;      //return pointer to objects so they
                                     //can be used elsewhere in the application
    }

    else 
    {
        //do some things
        //..

        if (timeToLeaveStateFoo)
        {
            //  how to free up memory at location "thingPtr" ??
            //  can't use delete(thingPtr)

            return bar();  //where bar is defined similarly     
        }

        else {return vPtr;}
    }
}
```

I apologize if this isn't exactly a concrete example, I'm trying to boil down the problem into the relevant bits. I guess the bottom line is **is there a way to free the memory allocated by "new" without explicity referencing the pointer returned by "new". I know the address, shouldn't that be sufficient?**

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you just invoke `delete`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, is there a problem with `Thing *p = vPtr; delete p; vPtr = bar();`

Comment: If you wrote the allocation and deallocation parts in assembly, you probably could do what you are asking. However, because you want the compiler to handle the memory for you, you must supply the original pointer to the compiler.

Comment: You only need a pointer value of the right type with the right address. C++ does not keep track how you came to that.

Comment: Thanks guys. Again, I apologize if I was too vague. I started writing a long edit with more context, when Deduplicator's comment came in. It was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not reference the original pointer explicitly when calling `delete`. You just pass a copy of the value originally returned by `new`.

Because your program is always only in one of the two states, which both have some huge objects, you might consider using a union of anonymous structures containing the neccessary objects for each state and placement new/delete. Still, that would probably a severe case of premature optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you couldn't solve this with a simple class hierarchy and virtual methods:

```
class A {
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  virtual ~A();
};

class Foo : public A {
  virtual void doStuff() { /* do "foo" stuff here ... */ }
};

class Bar : public A {
  virtual void doStuff() { /* do "bar" stuff here ... */ }
};

A *a_factory(bool first_time) {
  if (first_time) { return new Foo(); }
  else { return new Bar(); }
}

void baz(A *&thing) {
  a->foo(); // do regular foo stuff ...

  if (some_test) {
    delete a;
    a = a_factory(false);
    // ...
  }
}
```

What's stopping you design from doing things along these lines?

Comment: The only thing that is probably stopping me is the fact that I don't know much about C/C++. I'm a relative newcomer, but my background is in embedded h/w. I'm used to writing in assembly and keeping track of registers and memory contents, so my first instinct is "Hey, I know there's data at blah-blah address, now that I'm done doing x and ready to do y, let me repurpose that memory for state y"

Comment: You'll be better off in the long run (and likely even in the short run) if you use C/C++ more like the way it was designed to be used.  Save yourself a lot of unnecessary suffering and learn a bit more of the language, rather than trying to use it as if it was a fancy assembler.  A screwdriver makes a lousy hammer, and vice versa...

Comment: No sweat, sorry if I really overlooked the core issue you were having. If you're not even accustomed to malloc/free, new/delete might be a little hairy. C++ is really all about semantics of object lifetimes with automated setup/teardown code. A whole different world definitely.